# Git fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/master

Tags: git, dropbox

I am using `Dropbox` to sync a `git` repository, but now when I try and `push` I am getting an error:

```
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/master (MacBook-Pro's conflicted copy 2012-10-07)'
```

So, it seems that Dropbox detected a conflict and created a copy. Ok, no problem, so I deleted the conflicted file. Still, getting the above git error though.

```
$ git checkout master
    M   index.html
    Already on 'master'
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Cleanup repo"
    [master ff6f817] Cleanup repo
    1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
$ git push
    fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/master (MacBook-Pro's conflicted copy 2012-10-07)'
    The remote end hung up unexpectedly`
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 178):

make a backup of your repo if you aren't sure about this one, because these commands are irreversible.

first, go to your repo directory.

```
cd myrepo
```

then recursively search for the conflicted files and delete them

```
find . -type f -name "* conflicted copy*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

lastly, remove any "conflicted" references from git's packed-refs file

```
awk '!/conflicted/' .git/packed-refs > temp && mv temp .git/packed-refs
```

Comment: for macos users `find . -type f -name "* conflicted copy*" -delete`

Answer (score 42):

The conflicted file could be in multiple places, I would look into:

```
.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/
.git/logs/refs/heads/
.git/refs/remotes/origin/
.git/refs/heads/
```

Or you might look everywhere in the `.git` subdirectory: `find . -name '*conflicted*'`

Or, otherwise, list the active branches with `git branch -a` and delete (`git branch -d`) anything suspicious.

Comment: There are conflicted files everywhere inside of `.git`. I went through and deleted them all, and its fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin Glad I could help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: On Mac OS X use: `find . -name '*conflicted*'` (Edit: format)

Comment: @xgMz Thanks, I will update my answer, as your solution has general validity.

Comment: With a simple `find` I got hold of a single conflicting file and manually fixed the problem with two `mv`. Doing this slowly and reasoning step by step is the safest route.

Answer (score 8):

This also happen to our team when my colleague push his changes and shutdown the PC before Dropbox get updated.

I solved it so simply.

Just deleted the conflicted copy. (XXXX's conflicted copy yyyy-mm-dd)

And pull it normally.

Note that my colleague had the changes before messed up. And he push his changes again. This time no shutdown. :)

Comment: worked absolutely perfect for me :) thx - for me dropbox created some strange string filename which was not compatible to "update"

Comment: This worked for me!  There was a file with "conflicted copy" in the name in the /refs/heads folder and deleting that, then pull/push and all is well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was able to delete all the conflicted files from my .git folder, but I continued to get errors about files that no longer existed.

The fix for me was opening up `.git/refs/packed_refs` and deleting lines that contained the text "conflicted".

Answer (score 1):

For me it was giving error:
**`fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/tags/r0.2:3'`**

You can go to **/.git/packed_refs** file and delete the line for `refs/tags/r0.2:3`

Then it started working. But why it happened in the first place I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `git checkout master` first to get on the healthy, well-named branch.

Comment: Updated output in the original post.

Comment: Hm, could you try a full `git push origin master`, and also paste the the output of `git branch -a` please?

Comment: Same error here... trying `git branch -a` results in this very error!

Comment: The problem is on the remote repository, so pulling or checking out does not solve it. The other answers above refer to fixing directly the files on the remote and work perfectly. YOUR ADVISE IS VERY GOOD but it is not an answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error

> fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/somebranch (1)'

for the following command

```
git branch
```

Then, I searched for erroneous name (branch name followed by (1) ) using the command

```
find . -name 'somebranch (1)'
```

And it showed the following result

> ./.git/refs/heads/somebranch (1)

Which is some duplicated version of *somebranch* IMO. So, I removed this by executing the find command following by delete

```
find . -name 'somebranch (1)' -print -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Then the branch command run successfully

```
git branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounterd the similar error such as

```
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/user-search-api (Sithu's conflicted copy 2016-01-08)'
```

Simply deletion of the file `.git/refs/heads/user-search-api (Sithu's conflicted copy 2016-01-08)` in the remote Dropbox repository did solve the problem.